# Place text one below the other or on the same row but with extra space - in a mathematical formula

Tags: math-mode, color, line-breaking

I am running the following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\[ \text{Kelly MovieBot}: \colorbox{green!85}{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}} \\
   & \text{And Chill}: \colorbox{cyan!85}{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}}\\
   & \text{Movie Bot}: \colorbox{cyan!85}{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}} \]
\end{document}
```

But the words do not seem to be placed one below the other.

My output so far:

[image]

Desired output (option 1):

Kelly MovieBot: Green rectangle 
And Chill: Cyan rectangle 
MovieBot: Cyan rectangle

Desired output (option 2):

On the same row but at least with extra space between a rectangle and the next keyword. For example,

Kelly MovieBot: Green rectangle (space) And Chill: Cyan rectangle (space) MovieBot: Cyan rectangle

Comment: Why you surround the whole things in `\[ ... \]`? A `\parbox` or `varwidth` environment is more appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for the note @muzimuzhiZ. Can you post an example using the appropriate packages and the code to successfully get the desired output? It would be really helpful to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you employ a two-column `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{@{} rl @{}}
Kelly MovieBot & \colorbox{green!85}{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}} \\ \addlinespace
And Chill      & \colorbox{cyan!85 }{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}} \\ \addlinespace
Movie Bot      & \colorbox{cyan!85 }{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{}}} 
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as expected and since is only one given so far I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities with code as simple as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{Kelly MovieBot: {\color{green!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}}\qquad And Chill: {\color{cyan!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}}\qquad
   Movie Bot: {\color{cyan!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}}
}
\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Kelly MovieBot: & \color{green!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}\\[1.5ex]
    And Chill: & \color{cyan!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}\\[1.5ex]
   Movie Bot: & \color{cyan!85}\rule[-6pt]{18pt}{18pt}
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bernard. Your answer interprets both desired outputs. Thanks for your post, and I will keep it in mind for later use. Appreciate your effort.